# How to show popup image in category page

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to load `image popup` in category page , right now only `image thumb` i can access.

```
<div class="image">
  <a href="<?php echo $product['popup']; ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
  </a>
</div>
```

i copy code from product

```
if ($category_info['image']) {
    $this->data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
} else {
    $this->data['popup'] = '';
}
```

and paste under controller/product/category.php but i just get error message

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: popup in <b>/home ...
```

*Opencart version : v1.5.5.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution,

go to controller\product\category.php line 212 paste

```
if ($result['image']) {
    $popup = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'));
} else {
    $popup = false;
}
```

then line 244 after

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
```

paste

```
'popup'       => $popup,
```

Comment: So accept (by clicking on the tick on the left to the answer) You own answer to know the question is correctly answered.